# neural network decision boundary

Tags: neural-network

For the XOR problem, 2 decision boundaries are needed to solve it using 2 inputs neurons, 2 hidden neurons, 1 output neuron. From the book "Neural Network Design" on page 84, the author says that "each neuron in the network divides the input space into two regions."

In the xor network, there are 3 neurons excluding the inputs. Therefore 3 decision boundaries should be drawn. But most books show only 2 decision boundaries for the xor problem. Can someone explain why is it so?